# (Noticeable / Considerable / Eye-catching) progress

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, collocations

I am looking for an English fixed collocation for a kind of progress which is so significant and outstanding that is distinct compared to other achievements.

I am well aware that there are so many ways in English to refer to the same thing; some collocations like "**tremendous** progress", "**great** progress," etc. But what I need to convey should be directly related to eyes like "**eye-catching**" (though I have my doubts if the adjective "eye-catching" works in this combination as I could not find any reliable source for it surfing the net).

Please have a look on the example below and let me know if all the choices work there?

If so, is there any difference between them (while more or less, they mean the same to me.)

If not, then why?

> Over the past year, Nikodinov had been making ............. under the guidance of her coach, Yelena Tcherkasskaia, a former Bolshoi ballerina.

a. noticeable progress 
b. considerable progress 
c. eye-catching progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer:

a. and b. are correct and very much likely, while c. is not.

### Explanation:

There is difference in the three terms you so suggest. Going one at a time.

> Over the past year, Nikodinov had been making **eye-catching** progress under the guidance of her coach, Yelena Tcherkasskaia, a former Bolshoi ballerina.

**eye-catching** - *immediately appealing or noticeable; striking.*

As the definition says, it is something immediately appealing. However, progress can't be really termed as striking at the first go. You can't really comment someone's progress to be eye-catching, since you have no idea whether they made any at all or not. It may happen that they were great from the very beginning. In that case, ***eye-catching skills*** would be the correct term. You can use this adjective with jewellery, posters, banners, etc., but not really with the progress of a person.

---

> Over the past year, Nikodinov had been making **noticeable** progress under the guidance of her coach, Yelena Tcherkasskaia, a former Bolshoi ballerina.

**noticeable** - *easily seen or noticed; clear or apparent* **or** *noteworthy*

This, as the definition itself says, is clearly self-explanatory. The difference is, when saying this term we imply the hidden meaning that the person standing in  front of us (the addresser) can themselves look how far she has come from where she was a year earlier.

We also get an alternative word from this, that is, **noteworthy**.

> Over the past year, Nikodinov had been making ***noteworthy*** progress under the guidance of her coach, Yelena Tcherkasskaia, a former Bolshoi ballerina.

---

> Over the past year, Nikodinov had been making **considerable** progress under the guidance of her coach, Yelena Tcherkasskaia, a former Bolshoi ballerina.

**considerable** - *(of a person) having merit or distinction.*

This would mean that her progress is worth rewarding, one that belongs to a distinction class.

---

#### Alternatives:

- Over the past year, Nikodinov had been making **significant** progress under the guidance of her coach, Yelena Tcherkasskaia, a former Bolshoi ballerina.
- Over the past year, Nikodinov had been making **notable** progress under the guidance of her coach, Yelena Tcherkasskaia, a former Bolshoi ballerina.
- Over the past year, Nikodinov had been making **remarkable** progress under the guidance of her coach, Yelena Tcherkasskaia, a former Bolshoi ballerina.
- Over the past year, Nikodinov had been making **outstanding** progress under the guidance of her coach, Yelena Tcherkasskaia, a former Bolshoi ballerina.

---

This might not be the best resource, but it may seldom be helpful for someone.

1. [noticeable vs considerable vs eye-catching](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=noticeable%20progress%2Cconsiderable%20progress%2Ceye-catching%20progress&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnoticeable%20progress%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsiderable%20progress%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceye%20-%20catching%20progress%3B%2Cc0)
2. [significant vs remarkable vs notable vs outstanding](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=significant%20progress%2C%20remarkable%20progress%2C%20notable%20progress%2C%20outstanding%20progress&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csignificant%20progress%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremarkable%20progress%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnotable%20progress%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutstanding%20progress%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Thank you very much Dhanishtha. I will let you know if it comes to any further question regarding the same topic.

Comment: @A-friend Not a problem. Feel free to ask them. Also don't feel obliged to accept answers just because I am the only one answering it, someone else might provide an excellent answer which is far better than mine. Accept only if you feel it solved your problems, at least of now. You might have difficulties later which you can come here and put forth anytime.

Comment: I'd like to applaud you for you compassion and understanding Dhanishtha. It's clear while our cultures are too close you understand my mannerisms and reactions towards posters. I will let you know about further possible questions. Thank you very much again.